# How to use p:blockUI with p:tabView

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I want to create tabs with progress bar. Something like this:

```
<p:tabView id="tabs" dynamic="true" cache="false">
    <p:tab id="tab1" title="tab1" >
        <ui:include src="tab1.xhtml" />
    </p:tab>
    <p:tab id="tab2" title="tab2" >
        <ui:include src="tab2.xhtml" />
    </p:tab>

    <p:blockUI block="tabs" trigger="tabs">  
        LOADING
    </p:blockUI>  
</p:tabView>
```

But it's not working. Can you help me to correct my mistake?

Answer (score 4):

**Try this:**

```
<p:tabView id="tabs">

  <p:ajax event="tabChange" onstart="BUI.show()" oncomplete="BUI.hide()" />

  <p:tab id="tab1" title="tab1">
    <h:outputtext value="TAB 1" />
  </p:tab>

  <p:tab id="tab2" title="tab2">
    <h:outputtext value="TAB 2" />
  </p:tab>

</p:tabView>

<p:blockUI widgetVar="BUI" block="tabs">
  LOADING
</p:blockUI>
```

Comment: It's not working properly. The body of the tabs is not loaded at all. I don't see any bugs in Firebug.

Comment: Try it without dynamic and cache properties and also without <ui:include/>. Check if it is working. If it works add what you removed one by one until it is broken again. Im gonna simplify my answer with an update according to this comment.

Answer (score 0):

Following code works for me (Primefaces 5.2)

```
<p:blockUI block="tabs" widgetVar="tabsBlocker">  
    LOADING
</p:blockUI>  

<p:tabView id="tabs" dynamic="true" cache="false" 
    onTabChange="PF('tabsBlocker').show()" 
    onTabShow="PF('tabsBlocker').hide()">

  <p:tab id="tab1" title="tab1" >
      <ui:include src="tab1.xhtml" />
  </p:tab>

  <p:tab id="tab2" title="tab2" >
      <ui:include src="tab2.xhtml" />
  </p:tab>

</p:tabView>
```